# Gradle fails build during clover analysis due to a caught exception in a unit test

Tags: java, testng, gradle, clover

I'm using Gradle to run Clover test coverage analysis for TestNG unit tests. I've discovered that if a method I'm testing catches/handles an exception the gradle build will fail due to a failed test - even if the test doesn't fail. I run the TestNG test directly from Eclipse and it reports that everything passes, but when I run it from Gradle it fails:

```
13:46:03.741 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test] Finished tests
13:46:03.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.TestLogger] 13 tests completed, 1 failure
13:46:03.742 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':artim-decision:test'
13:46:03.750 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
13:46:03.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
13:46:03.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
13:46:03.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
13:46:03.752 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':aaaaa-decision:test'.
13:46:03.754 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > There were failing tests. See the report at C:\Dev\AAAAA\trunk\aaaaa-decision\build\reports\tests.
13:46:03.754 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
13:46:03.755 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
13:46:03.755 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':artim-decision:test'.
13:46:03.755 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
13:46:03.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
13:46:03.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
13:46:03.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:34)
13:46:03.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
13:46:03.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:172)
13:46:03.756 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
13:46:03.757 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:111)
13:46:03.757 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
13:46:03.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.java:32)
13:46:03.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:55)
13:46:03.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
13:46:03.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
13:46:03.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
13:46:03.758 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
13:46:03.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
13:46:03.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:250)
13:46:03.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)
13:46:03.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
13:46:03.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
13:46:03.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36)
13:46:03.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
13:46:03.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
13:46:03.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
13:46:03.760 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
13:46:03.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
13:46:03.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
13:46:03.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
13:46:03.761 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:103)
13:46:03.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
13:46:03.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
13:46:03.762 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
13:46:03.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
13:46:03.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
13:46:03.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
13:46:03.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
13:46:03.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
13:46:03.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155)
13:46:03.763 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
13:46:03.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
13:46:03.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:42)
13:46:03.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:28)
13:46:03.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:32)
13:46:03.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:21)
13:46:03.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:238)
13:46:03.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:222)
13:46:03.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
13:46:03.764 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:53)
13:46:03.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:51)
13:46:03.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.Execution.execute(Execution.java:28)
13:46:03.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:39)
13:46:03.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
13:46:03.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:51)
13:46:03.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:33)
13:46:03.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
13:46:03.765 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the report at C:\Dev\AAAAA\trunk\aaaaa-decision\build\reports\tests.
13:46:03.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:386)
13:46:03.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
13:46:03.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:102)
13:46:03.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:93)
13:46:03.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
13:46:03.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
13:46:03.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:150)
13:46:03.766 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:145)
13:46:03.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:495)
13:46:03.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:484)
13:46:03.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:60)
13:46:03.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 54 more
13:46:03.767 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
13:46:03.767 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
13:46:03.768 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
```

Has anyone encountered this before? There's nothing in the generated test reports that gives me any clues.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information, like the output of `gradle -v`, the exact error (including stack trace) shown in the test report, how you set up Gradle to run Clover, whether the same problem exists when Clover isn't in the loop, etc.

Comment: Please post your build script. Also you could give the [Gradle Clover plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin) a try which reliefs you of most of the setup.

Answer (score 1):

You should run gradle with `--debug` and then You will likely see a stacktrace with a hint to the cause.